# How to allow clicking a button "n" times and then disappear for a month

Tags: android, date, button, time

Implement a simple button, which changes information but I need that information only change 3 times, I need to disappear that button
When Exceed of the three clicks but I do not know how to do it and how to disappear it for 3 months

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a counter and a date variable to store the information. Save them in the shared preferences and get them whenever you want.

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MySharedPrefName", MODE_PRIVATE); 

final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button_id);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
          int counter = prefs.getInt("counter", 0); //0 is the default value.
          counter++;
          editor.putInt("counter", counter);
          if(counter == 3){
              button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              Date myDate = ;
              String format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
              String prefData = SimpleDateFormat(format).format(myDate);
              prefs.putString("date", prefDate); 
          }
      }
 });
```

After that, you can get the date from the shared preferences and check if 3 months have already passed in order to modify the visibility of the button.

To check if the 3 months have alredy passed use this method

```
private boolean havePassedThreeMonths(){


  //GET CURRENT DATE
  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
  Date currentDate = c.getTime();


  //GET DATE FROM PREFERENCES
  prefDate = prefs.getString("Date", "");
  String format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
  Date date = new SimpleDateFormat(format).parse(prefDate);

  //Compare the two dates
  return monthsBetweenDates(date, currentDate) > 3;
}
```

Here the monthsBetweenDates method:

```
public int monthsBetweenDates(Date startDate, Date endDate){

        Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
        start.setTime(startDate);

        Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
        end.setTime(endDate);

          int monthsBetween = 0;
            int dateDiff = end.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)-start.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);      

if(dateDiff<0) {
                int borrrow = end.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);           
                 dateDiff = (end.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+borrrow)-start.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                 monthsBetween--;

if(dateDiff>0) {
                     monthsBetween++;
                 }
            }
            else {
                monthsBetween++;
            }      
            monthsBetween += end.get(Calendar.MONTH)-start.get(Calendar.MONTH);      
            monthsBetween  += (end.get(Calendar.YEAR)-start.get(Calendar.YEAR))*12;      
            return monthsBetween;
     }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: And how can I check when the 3 months have passed? @fn5341

Comment: i did this, check please for check the date ` long fechaFuturo = new Date().getTime() + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(60, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        preferences.edit().putLong("fechaFutura", fechaFuturo);

        if(preferences.getLong("fechaFutura", fechaFuturo) == new Date().getTime()){
            mCambiarFotoPErfil.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
`